# Fitnesse: Open file relative to current page

Tags: fitnesse

Is there a simple way to open a file from within a fixture, using a path relative to the current wiki page? The files are actually being stored in the same directory as the wiki page.

I'm using those files to store some expected data, that is later compared to the data actually measured while executing a test. Embedding the data in the wiki page would simply be too much.

I've already spent quite some time searching through the API, but couldn't find anything except how to access files in Fitness' root folder.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to store the files somewhere relative to the FitNesse root and put the relative path on the wiki page

|calculate some results|

|compare to expected at|relativepath|

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option, as the files and the tests that use them are the result of a model based generator process. The generator writes its output to a temporary folder and does not have access to the FitNesse root.

Answer (score 0):

To create/access pages path relative to the current wiki page use this syntax:

```
>RelativePage
```

`>` makes path relative from current page.